# DNNClassifier - How to obtain the parameters of various layers after training

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

```
def Classifier(parameters):

    learning = parameters[0]
    layers = parameters[1]
    nodes = parameters[2]
    hidden_layers =  [nodes for i in range(layers)]
    activation_function = tf.nn.sigmoid if parameters[3] == 0 else tf.nn.relu



    age_var = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Age')
    shape_var = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Shape')
    margin_var = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Margin')
    density_var =tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Density')
    features = [age_var,shape_var,margin_var,density_var]

    return tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=hidden_layers, 
                                      n_classes=2,
                                      feature_columns=features, 
                                      activation_fn=activation_function,
                                      model_dir='/tmp/'+uuid.uuid4().hex,
                                      optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning),
                                      config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=250,
                                                                        save_checkpoints_secs=None,
                                                                        save_summary_steps=500))
```

Is it possible to get the parameters of the various layers after training the model defined as above ?

If yes could you give me th commands for that

I am new/learning tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

I simple way would be to loop over the list of variable names of the `DNNClassifier` model returned by the `Classifier` function and call `get_variable_value` passing the name of each:

```
for variable_name in model.get_variable_names():
    print('Parameter Name: ', variable_name, ' Parameter Value: ', model.get_variable_value(variable_name))
```

But this would still need you to pick out the weights of each single layer (`/hiddenlayer_0/...`, `/hiddenlayer_1/...` etc is what the `DNNClassifier` names its model's hidden layers by default).

You will have to loop over these param names and fetch the values of only those params for which the name has `hiddenlayer_<num>` in it, which means performing some string pattern matching. E.g. :

```
hidden_layer_0_params = {}
for variable_name in model.get_variable_names():
    if variable_name.startswith("dnn/hiddenlayer0"):
        hidden_layer_0_params[variable_name] = model.get_variable_value(variable_name)
```

You can help improve this though! One way is to create and compile a separate `tf.keras` model first and then convert it into the required estimator instance using the `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator` function.

The reason its advantageous is that `tf.keras` names its model params a little better, and they don't have a `dnn/hiddenlayer_` prefix for the layer param names by default. For example, the param names for a `tf.keras` model will have no prefixes and are formatted like `layer_with_weights-0/bias` by default.

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/keras_model_to_estimator) is a good tutorial to create an estimator instance from a keras model and using it for training and evaluation..